# How can I make a UIRefreshControl smaller?

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

UIRefreshControl uses a very large spinner:

[image]

I'd like to resize it (the frame of the spinner, not the pull-down length!) to look more like this:

[image]

I can't see anything in [the reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/) about how do this, and though it inherits from UIView, setting the frame doesn't work (possibly because I'm using AutoLayout?)

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. Just select from the inspector:

[image]

I think you use a large one.

Also you can do this:

```
import QuartzCore
activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
```

This will create an activity indicator 15px wide

Comment: Since I didn't want to bother wiring up the auto layout bits in IB, I can't do it that way (though I normally would!). But your transform solution is perfect! Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you ;)

Comment: there is no Activity Indicator property to modify in interface builder since the question was referring to a refresh control activity indicator and not just a plain activity indicator.  the correct answer to this should be the one below from @ return true

Answer (score 17):

Simply use `refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);`

No need to import QuartzCore or doing whatever else.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Update: Swift 5

`refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)`